# Reverse proxy slows down ajax

Tags: ajax, reverse, reverse-proxy

I have a situation where special.company.com is reverse proxied to a server with address 123.123.123.123.

At the server locally, the ajax loads in 600ms.  However, when running the same application throught special.company.com, it takes approximately 1.7s.

Is reverse proxy the main cause of the slow down? How can we find a solution to this?

Comment: Is there are better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a TCP port forward so you can test the ajax load bypassing the reverse proxy server. This will determine if it's a problem with your remote internet connectivity, or computer.

Your problem requires a **process of elimination**, to find the cause for sure.

Comment: even accessing from 123.123.123.123 (remotely) reads as 600ms , but special.company.com reversed proxy to 123 just is slow 1.7s can i conclude with that?